# Does Mysql use exclusive locks by default when doing UPDATE queries?

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-locking

**Environment : Mysql5.7 InnoDB**

A Connection

```
start transaction; --> <1>

SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id = 1 lock in share mode; --> <2>
```

B Connection

```
UPDATE table_a SET name = 'blah' WHERE id = 1; --> <3>
```

Function Flow : <1> -> <2> -> <3>

Conclusion : <2> query result is `blahblah`. But, B Query(<3>) waits.

B Query is no lock.

Why do I get this result?
Does Mysql use exclusive locks by default when doing UPDATE queries?

Comment: Why do you get what result? There is no result here. And how did you form your 'conclusion'?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE queries needs to hold an exclusive lock on the rows it examines, so it will wait until there is no other lock on those rows.

SELECT queries do not block UPDATE queries, unless the SELECT is a locking query with the FOR UPDATE, FOR SHARE, or LOCK IN SHARE MODE clauses.

If you use the transaction isolation level SERIALIZABLE, then *all* SELECT statements implicitly have LOCK IN SHARE MODE, so they will block UPDATEs. But this is not the default configuration, so you would have to request it deliberately.

Comment: I made a mistake. A query is in Shared Mode. I understand that Exclusive Lock does not have access when in Shared Lock Mode. But, Why B Query(simple update query) waiting when using Shared Lock?

Comment: Because an exclusive lock means that no other lock may exist. The UPDATE must wait until it is the only one that holds a lock of any type on the rows it examines.

Comment: I'm sorry, Does your answer mean UPDATE = Exclusive Lock?

Comment: I see why my first sentence of my answer was ambiguous. I've edited it, hopefully to be more clear.

Comment: Hi @Bill Karwin, does DELETE also hold an exclusive lock?

Comment: @Daniel, read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html

Comment: marked as useful answer, great @Bill Karwin, thanks a lot I'll check it out.